# Commutative algebra, Krull dimension. Eisenbud, Exercise 10.6

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I need help to solve this exercise. If anyone can help, thanks in advance!

Let $R=k[x,y,s,t]/(xs-yt)$ and $S=R/(x,y)=k[s,t]$. Let $P=(s,t)\subset R$. Show that $\operatorname{codim} P=1$ but $\operatorname{codim} PS=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $xs-yt$ is an irreducible polynomial in $k[x,y,s,t]$.
If the height of $P$ in $R$ is greater than $1$, then there is a prime ideal $Q$ such that $(xs-yt)\subsetneq Q\subsetneq P$, and thus the height of $P$ in $k[x,y,s,t]$ is at least $3$, a contradiction.
Since $PS=(s,t)k[s,t]$ we get the height of $PS$ equals $2$.

Comment: I don't understand. "$(xs−yt)⊊Q⊊P$, and thus the height of $P$ in $k[x,y,s,t]$ is at least 3, a contradiction." Why is it a contradiction? Better, why is it impossible that exist $(xs−yt)⊊Q⊊(s,t)$.

Comment: And why $PS$ has codimension 2? Is it a sort of product of dimension?

Comment: @user149240: $\text{codim}(P, k[x,y,s,t]) \ge 3$ contradicts Krull's Altitude Theorem, since $P$ is generated by $2$ elements. Existence of the chain $(xs - yt) \subsetneq Q \subsetneq P$ comes from assuming $P$ has height $\ge 2$ in $R$ (recall $(xs - yt) = (0)$ in $R$). For your second comment, consider the chain of primes $0 \subsetneq (s) \subsetneq (s,t) = PS$ in $k[s,t]$.

Comment: very good, I understood ;) thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about the geometry?  $R$ corresponds to a cone (a three dimensional
cone in $4$-space).  The ideals $P$ and $Q := (x,y)$ each cut out a plane in $4$-space; these two planes meet in a single point --- the cone point.

Each plane has codimension one in the cone; this corresponds to the fact that each
of $P$ and $Q$ has codimension one as prime ideals.

But $PS = P (R/Q)$ has codimension two, because $S/PS = R/(P,Q)$, corresponding to
the intersection of the two planes, which is the single cone point.  (And a point
has codimension two in the plane that $S$ corresponds to.)